# Desktop App inside a Windows 8 Store App container

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, desktop-application

Is it possible to create a Metro App as a *container screen* that holds a traditional Desktop App within it?

I'm trying to figure out a way to force some applications to run seamlessly with the new interface, removing the need of alternating every time to the Desktop.

Does anyone imagine any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do some sort of a remote desktop session within your window if you work at Citrix...